# Ruby is_a?Module is returning true for a class defined inside module

Tags: ruby, recursion, module

"puts A::B::C.is_a?Module" from below code is returning true, should it be false as C is a class inside module.

```
module A
    module B
        class C
            puts A::B.is_a?Class
            puts A::B.is_a?Module
            
            puts A::B::C.is_a?Class
            puts A::B::C.is_a?Module 
        end
    end
end
```

```
false
true
true
true
```

I want to write a recursive function that checks on class or module instance to take actions. Please find below code snippets.

```
           def recursive(rootModule)
                sampleList = []
                rootModule.constants.map do |c|
                    nextLayer = rootModule.const_get(c)

                    if nextLayer.is_a? Module
                        return recursive(nextLayer)
                    elsif nextLayer.is_a? Class
                        return sampleList << "alpha"
                    end
                end
            end
```

Comment: A `Class` "is a" `Module`. `Object#is_a?`: *"Returns `true` if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the superclasses of obj or modules included in obj."* `Class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`. You could check `nextLayer.class == Module`

Comment: As noted by @engineersmnky, in ruby `Class` inherits from `Module`, so every Class is also a Module.

Comment: `elsif nextLayer.is_a? Class` - in your snippet they don't, but in general classes _can_ contain other nested classes/modules.

Answer (score 1):

`is_a?` checks if an object is an instance of a class or any of its subclasses. `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, so `is_a? Module` will always return true for classes *and* modules.

Since `Module` is the more general type, instead of asking "Is this a module?", you should be asking "Is this module not a class?".

```rb
if nextLayer.is_a? Module
  # could be Module or Class
  if nextLayer.is_a? Class
    # code for handling Classes
  else
    # code for handling Modules
  end
else
  # not a Module (so also not a Class). not all constants are Modules!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As written above, `Object#is_a?` checks if an object is an instance of a class or any of its subclasses, and `Class` is a subclass of `Module`. So you can use `Object#instance_of?` method, which returns true if obj is an instance of the given class.

```
if nextLayer.instance_of? Class
  # process classes
elsif nextLayer.instance_of? Module
 # process modules
else
  # process other constants
end
```

Actually, the following code will also work

```
if nextLayer.is_a? Class
  # process classes
elsif nextLayer.is_a? Module
 # process modules
else
  # process other constants
end
```